# How do I use getline infile?

Tags: c++

When reading a file, any other commands that are not started with Create, Deposit, Withdraw, Balance need to be skipped and print out an error message. I'm trying with getline but I just can't get it right even though I have researched all around. And another problem I have is the Balance command is not read. How do I fix this?

Text file need to be read

```
Create 1 1000.01
Create 2 2000.02
Create 3 3000.03
Deposit 1 11.11
Deposit 2 22.22
Withdraw 4 5000.00
Create 4 4000.04
Withdraw 1 0.10
Balance 2
Withdraw 2 0.20
Deposit 3 33.33
Withdraw 4 0.40
Bad Command 65
Balance 1
Balance 2
Balance 3
Balance 4
```

This is my code

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Account.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream statFile;
    int account;
    double amount;
    double balance;
    string command;
    string junk;
    int id;
    Account* AccountArray[10] = { nullptr };
    Account* acc1;

    statFile.open("bank.txt");
    cout << "File opened." << endl;
    while (statFile >> command) {
        if (command == "Create")
        {
            statFile >> id >> amount;
            acc1 = new Account(id, amount);
            if (AccountArray[id] != nullptr)
                cout << "That account id already exist." << endl;
            else
                AccountArray[id] = acc1;
            cout << "Account number " << id << " created" << endl;
            cout << "with an initial balance of " << amount << endl;
        }
        else if (command == "Deposit")
        {
            statFile >> id >> amount;
            if (AccountArray[id] == nullptr)
                cout << "That account id #" << id << "does not exist" << endl;
            else 
                AccountArray[id]->deposit(amount);
            cout << "Deposited " << amount << " into account #" << id << endl;
            cout << "current balance is " << AccountArray[id]->getBalance() << endl;
        }
        else if (command == "Withdraw")
        {
            statFile >> id >> amount;
            if (AccountArray[id] == nullptr)
                cout << "That account id #" << id << " does not exist" << endl;
            else
                AccountArray[id]->withdraw(amount);
            cout << "Withdrew " << amount << " from account #" << id << endl;
            cout << "current balance is " << AccountArray[id]->getBalance() << endl;
        }
        else if (command == "Balance")
        {
            statFile >> id;
            if (AccountArray[id] == nullptr)
                cout << "That account id #" << id << " does not exist" << endl;
            else
                AccountArray[id]->getBalance();
            cout << "Current balance in account #" << id << " is " << AccountArray[id]->getBalance() << endl;
        }
        else if (command != "Create", "Deposit", "Withdraw", "Balance")
        {
                getline(inFile, junk);
            cout << "Unrecognized command" << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the way, `else if (command != "Create", "Deposit", "Withdraw", "Balance")` should just be `else`.  What you have written will happen to work only because `else if ("Balance")` evaluates to true.

Comment: `getline(inFile, junk);` will not compile.  You have no variable called `inFile`.  This should be `getline(statFile, junk);` -- if this is the _"can't get it right"_ issue you're complaining about, then you must learn to read compiler error messages.  If it's not, then please actually describe the problem you're having.

Comment: @paddy I've tried else but didn't see any difference.

Comment: @paddy I've changed to statFile as well. The problem I have is whenever the Balance command is read, it should cout the total balance of the account number go after that command, but It does not do that. And in a file there should be only those 4 command are read, any other commands should be skipped.

Comment: What happens if account id is larger than 9? Why do you use pointers to store the accounts? You could create an array `Account AccountArray[10]`. That would make the code simpler and it would fix the memory leak in your code. Instead of checking if the pointer is set you could add a boolean member variable `isCreated`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already noted in comments to OP, there are several compile and logical errors plus a memory leak in your solution:

1. `getline(inFile, junk);` should be changed to `getline(statFile, junk);`
2. `else if (command != "Create", "Deposit", "Withdraw", "Balance")` should be replaced by a simple `else`
3. missing `{}` on all `if-else` statements resulting in NPE:

```cpp
            if (AccountArray[id] == nullptr)
                cout << "That account id #" << id << " does not exist" << endl;
            else
                AccountArray[id]->withdraw(amount);
            cout << "Withdrew " << amount << " from account #" << id << endl;
            // Following line gets executed even for AccountArray[id] == nullptr
            cout << "current balance is " << AccountArray[id]->getBalance() << endl;

            // Fixed code:
            if (AccountArray[id] == nullptr)
            {
                cout << "That account id #" << id << " does not exist" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                AccountArray[id]->withdraw(amount);
                cout << "Withdrew " << amount << " from account #" << id << endl;
                cout << "current balance is " << AccountArray[id]->getBalance() << endl;
            }
```

4. Allocated memory for `Accounts` is not released. For every `new` in your program you should have a `delete`. Here's one way to do that:

```cpp
int main() {
  ...

  for(Account* a : AccountArray) {
    delete a;
  }

  return 0;
}
```